# ODOO JSON Looping Values

Tags: python, odoo

I need help looping values inside JSON. This is my code.
What I want is looping inside name, surname, email, and sms based on value in database.

````
    "emailBlacklist": False,
    "smsBlacklist": False,
    "updateExistingContacts": True,
    "emptyContactsAttributes": False,
    "fileBody": "NAME;SURNAME;EMAIL\n\"Smith\";\"John\";\"john.smith@example.com\"\n\"Roger\";"->Loop here
} ```

This is example of database.
Email                   Lastname    Firstname SMS
john6@example.com       Smith       John      3123456793
harry6#@example.com     Edmund      Harry     3111222226
how#ard6#@example.com   Stern       Howard    3777888902
credits@davy.ie Jane    Jane        Doe       2344556681
````

Comment: Are you using the json module for this? It would be nice to know what your using so we know how to help. Pandas seems like a good option

Comment: No module for json. What I want is just loop the filebody value.That is it. I don't know how to place the bracket.Thanks

Comment: The fileBody value is a string though. I would recommend using json module or even doing the parsing prior to export

Comment: Could you give me example for that. This API kind of new for me. Thanks

Comment: What api are you using

Comment: I am using import contact in sendinblue API.